# Netty WebScoketClientHandshaker not working

Tags: websocket, netty

i have a question. who can help me? it'll be very appreciate. i wanna make websocketclient but my code blocked at handShaker.handshake(ch).syncUninterruptibly();...
websocket server is working well becuase i've test it using JS.only netty client not working..

belows is my code

```
public void Start() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try{
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        URI uri = new URI(url);

        WebSocketClientHandshaker handShaker = WebSocketClientHandshakerFactory.newHandshaker(uri, WebSocketVersion.V13, null, false, null);
        WebSocketClientHandler handler = new WebSocketClientHandler(handShaker, actionHandlers);

        b.group(group)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast(new HttpClientCodec());
                pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(8192));
                pipeline.addLast(handler);
            }
        });

        ch = b.connect(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()).sync().channel();
        //handler.handShakeFuture().sync();
        handShaker.handshake(ch).syncUninterruptibly();
        ch.closeFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody knows? Nobody use netty now?